# Load balancer vs Service discovery?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, load-balancing, service-discovery

Hope everyone is doing well.

There is a question that is bugging me a lot. According to my understanding we were using service discovery to eliminate the needs of remembering the URL and port number of the microservices. Like If we have 10 instances of the same microservices then we were just accessing them via just only the name via service discovery. And it was already load balanced. Right?

But then the load balancer came into picture. And according to my understanding we are again doing the same thing, right?

We are using the load balancer to again eliminate the needs of remembering URL's and ports of the microservices, right?

Then my question is what is the fundamental difference that is making load balancer a load balancer and service discovery a service discovery?

Pardon my mistake. It may be my mis-understanding. But if you can please help it would be great.

Comment: load balancer is to distribute incoming network traffic across multiple servers,  service discovery is the process of locating and identifying services within a network. In many distributed systems, a load balancer use a service discovery underneath

Answer (score 1):

Awesome line of thinking, I propose to get to the bottom via Q&A :)

Let me pick one of questions: "We are using the load balancer to again eliminate the needs of remembering URL's and ports of the microservices, right?"

So how will a client know the address of the Load Balancer? It will be different for production and testing stages; and in a regionalized world, it may (or may not) be different in different regions.

The next dimension is the architecture of the service itself. It is not given that every independent node knows how to register itself with the service discovery. It completely ok to have several nodes be running behind a load balancer - in this case, the whole service looks like a singe box for the entire world. Clients still need to discover the load balancer.

p.s.
The idea that every service node independently registers itself to service discovery and clients discover and randomly connected to those - this concept often called "service mesh" - a middle ware to do all discovery, routing, failure detection, etc.